# Why is there no function to read/write a file in the Python standard library

Tags: python

I frequently use the two functions below to read the contents of a file to a string and to write a string to a file. To my knowledge these functions don't exist in the Python standard library and I'm curious why. The standard library module [shutil](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html) which has high level directory and files operations does not have this function, and I'm sure this was an explicit design choice not to have it in there. Namely I'd like to know the following:

- What are the potential reasons for not including it in Python Standard Library
- Are there any downsides to dealing with files this way (assuming one is aware that the whole file contents will be loaded into  memory)

**functions**

```
def read_file(path):
    with open(path) as f:
        return f.read()

def write_file(path, data):
    with open(path, 'wb') as f:
        return f.write(data)
```

To clarify I find the below more readable

```
write_file('/tmp/test', 'test')
```

then the below two alternatives:

```
open('/tmp/test', 'wb').write('test')

with open('/tmp/test', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Comment: Because they're silly and redundant.

Comment: A function which saves you from writing 1 line of code is hardly worth having ... Python often sacrifices succinctness for clarity.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: That should be an answer, not a comment imo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are both one-liners and you don't really need a function for them.

```
data = open("filename").read()
open("filename", "w").write(data)
```

In CPython, at least, the file is going to be closed immediately after you execute either of these statements because you're not keeping a reference to the file object. Making sure the file gets closed when an exception happens is not really an issue, especially in simple scripts.

In other Python implementations, such as Jython and IronPython, this may be more problematic. When it is, there's `with` (which you can also write on one line perfectly clearly):

```
with open("filename") as f: data = f.read()
```

If you find it clearer to have helper functions like the one you wrote, by all means write them; they are clear enough. But they are hardly necessary and most Python programmers wouldn't use them.

Comment: thank you for the clear and polite answer. That was all I was looking for.

Comment: -1 I respectfully disagree. While this *works*, I maintain that it is evil (where "evil" is not to be taken as moral judgement but just as strong opinion). If you get into this habit, you limit yourself to small scripts not opening a lot of files running on a particular Python implementation, where you could go the recommended way and have code you write without thinking work flawlessly *everywhere* (well, except in an asynchronous server I suppose) at no cost at all. I don't consider the extra line for the `with` a cost. It makes it *more obvious* that/where the file is opened and closed.

Comment: `open_and_close =  open; open_and_close("filename").read()`  ;-)

Comment: @kindall I can tell from the emoticon that it's a joke, but how about about a serious respone? Also, the name `open_and_close` is very misleading because it doesn't close anything ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Aside from them both being possible in one-liners like the @Kindall answer...

Your examples pass in a lot of options, rendering them for specific tasks.

```
def read_file(path):
    with open(path) as f:
        return f.read()
```

Open takes a handful of arguments.  http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open

> open(name[, mode[, buffering]])

you can also read a file multiples ways:

- `read` http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=readline#file.read
- `readline` http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=readline#file.readline
- `readlines` http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=readline#file.readlines
- `xreadline` http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=readline#file.xreadlines (deprecated and replaced with `for line in file` )
- and that's just the start. the entire module gives you ways to manipulate a file.

Depending on the size of the file, the content types, and what you'd want to do with it -- you'd want to switch things up.

Having a "read()" and "write()" function like you wrote is useful for dealing with small text files - but it can be troublesome in other situations.

For example, if you're trying to read a 9GB log file - reading everything into memory with your idea would cause a lot of problems on most current machines ( which have 4-8GB ram ).  And if that logfile were in a binary format, you would have issues working with the data.

Since you can read/write a file easily with a one-liner by chaining these commands, it makes little sense to me to have another, more limited, way to deal with files.